# Ошибка соединения при парсинге сайта python - ConnectionError

Tags: python, исключения, exception-handler

Ошибка соединения при парсинге сайта python - ConnectionError -  Попытка установить соединение была безуспешной, т.к. от другого компьютера за требуемое время не получен нужный отклик, или было разорвано уже установленное соединение из-за неверного отклика уже подключенного компьютера'))

Даже при первом соединении и вообще постоянно, дошёл максимум до 7-ой итераци из 53-ёх, пытался всячески исправить но тчетно. Кто-то знает как вылечить ?

Вот код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json 
import csv
from time import sleep
import random

# url = "https://health-diet.ru/table_calorie/?utm_source=leftMenu&utm_medium=table_calorie"

headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/96.0.4664.93 Safari/537.36',  
}


# req = requests.get(url, headers=headers) 
# src = req.text
# print(src)

# with open('index2.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # file.write(src)

# with open('index2.html', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # src = file.read()

# soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
# all_products_hrefs = soup.find_all(class_="mzr-tc-group-item-href")

# all_categories_dict = {}
# for item in all_products_hrefs:
    # item_text = item.text
    # item_href = "https://health-diet.ru" + item.get('href')

    # all_categories_dict[item_text] = item_href

# with open('all_categories_dict.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    # json.dump(all_categories_dict, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)


with open("all_categories_dict.json", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    all_categories = json.load(file)

iteration_count = int(len(all_categories)) - 1
count = 0
print(f"Total iterations: {iteration_count}")

for category_name, category_href in all_categories.items():

    rep = [",", " ", "-", "'"]
    for item in rep:
        if item in category_name:
            category_name = category_name.replace(item, "_")

    req = requests.get(url=category_href, headers=headers)
    src = req.text

    with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(src)

    with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.html", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        src = file.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")

    # Checking the page for the presence of a table with products
    alert_block = soup.find(class_="uk-alert-danger")
    if alert_block is not None:
        continue

    # Collecting table headers
    table_head = soup.find(class_="mzr-tc-group-table").find("tr").find_all("th")
    product = table_head[0].text
    calories = table_head[1].text
    proteins = table_head[2].text
    fats = table_head[3].text
    carbohydrates = table_head[4].text

    with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.csv", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(
            (
                product,
                calories,
                proteins,
                fats,
                carbohydrates
            )
        )

    # Сollect product data
    products_data = soup.find(class_="mzr-tc-group-table").find("tbody").find_all("tr")

    product_info = []
    for item in products_data:
        product_tds = item.find_all("td")

        title = product_tds[0].find("a").text
        calories = product_tds[1].text
        proteins = product_tds[2].text
        fats = product_tds[3].text
        carbohydrates = product_tds[4].text

        product_info.append(
             {
                 "Title": title,
                 "Calories": calories,
                 "Proteins": proteins,
                 "Fats": fats,
                 "Carbohydrates": carbohydrates
             }
         )

        with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.csv", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow(
                (
                    title,
                    calories,
                    proteins,
                    fats,
                    carbohydrates
                )
            )
with open(f"data/{count}_{category_name}.json", "a", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(product_info, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

count += 1
print(f"# Iteration {count}. {category_name} recorder...")
iteration_count = iteration_count - 1

if iteration_count == 0:
    print("Job completed")
    break

print(f"Remaining iterations: {iteration_count}")
sleep(random.randrange(2, 4))
```

Мог где-то отступ втыкнуть пока сюда переносил
С обучающего видео, try-except пробовал, VPN пробовал, всё равно валится, не дальше 7-ой итерации (
ссылка сайта в переменной url вверху
видел что можно ещё proxy попробовать, но пока не разобрался как

Comment: Нужны детали. Какая библиотека используется, куда не получается достучаться. Что за 53 итерации. Лучше всего в вопрос добавить код, о котором едёт речь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

можно сделать примерно так:

```
try:
    iterations()
except ConnectionError:
    restart()
```

описание: когда выдает ошибку, заново запусти сервер

Comment: Попробовал всё равно падает